# Какой предлог лучше?

Tags: грамматика, предлоги

Какой предлог предпочесть в данном случае: "порча оформляется актом, где/в котором..."?

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта возможны. Выбор более предпочтительного может зависит от контекста, но вообще они равноправны. "Где" - более канцелярский вариант.

"Где" и "который" - это не предлоги, союзные слова.